# Migrating from Astronomer airflow setup to MWAA

Tags: mwaa

Currently we are using Apache airflow platform provided by Astronomer with Kubernetes executer and we are using PostgreSQL as a backend DB. Now we want move to MWAA. I want some help if anyone has done the same.

1. How to migrate existing DAGs and Metadata to MWAA ?
2. What are the things we need to take care before migration ?
3. Is there anyway we can migrate everything from current setup to MWAA ?

Please help me if anyone has any idea about this.

Comment: Totally unrelated but why are you migrating?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the official migration guide for MWAA from AWS: [Migrating to a new Amazon MWAA environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/migrationguide/migrating-to-new-mwaa.html). The documentation covers how to [migrate metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/migrationguide/key-considerations.html) and [key considerations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/migrationguide/key-considerations.html).

Please give it a read through. If you have a more specific question, feel free to post a new question.